# Is there a way to have custom responsive shapes inside React JS?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg

[image]

As you can see the above clipped rectangle with border radius is my target element to develop in code, also I want it to be responsive as well. Can someone educate me in how to achieve this??

I tried adding the svg inside react but couldnt achieve the responsiveness as svg's are related with viewboxes, heights & widths.